# Template format error: YAML not well-formed. Remove prohibited property Error

Tags: yaml, airflow, aws-cloudformation

The following Parameter block is throwing me Remove prohibited property Warning and in turn the ci make validate command is throwing an error: "Template format error: YAML not well-formed."

```
Parameters:
  Configuration:
    Description: The environment/configuration name
    Type: String
  AccountName:
    Description: AWS account name
    Type: String
  ServiceName:
    Description: Service name
    Type: String
    Default: kada
  S3BucketName:
    Description: S3 bucket name
    Type: String
  user:
    Description: Username
    Type: String
  client_id:
    Description: Client id
      Type: String
  token_url:
    Description: URL to fetch token
      Type: String
  post_url:
    Description: URL where json is posted
      Type: String
  domain:
    Description: KADA Domain
      Type: String
  post_token_url:
    Description: url to fetch token
      Type: String
```

The error is from the client id Parameter and continued for all other parameters saying remove prohibited property. I am new to cloud formation. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Got the fix! When declaring un Yaml, we cannot use `_` or white space in the variables, hence I used `camelcase` and got it fixed.